# Open local pdf file using pdf.js in firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, pdf.js

I am using `pdf.js` to extract annotations from pdf files in a firefox add-on. Everything works pretty well except opening local pdf files. `PDFJS.getDocument('http://...').then(function(pdf) { ...` works but `PDFJS.getDocument('file:///...').then(function(pdf) {` does not. 
I am getting this error: `Unexpected server response (0) while retrieving PDF ...`

Is this a cross-domain issue? I thought that shouldn't be a problem because my code is running from an extension. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file into a Uint8Array and pass it as `source` to `getDocument`.

Comment: Thanks! Any hints on how to do that? I can just pass the Uint8Array  to `getDocument` and I can create a using `new Uint8Array(...)` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251947/using-pdf-js-to-display-pdf-from-raw-data/11671655#11671655)). But I am not sure how to read a local file into a Uint8Array...

Comment: Use the [OS.File module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread) (accept the answer if you find it useful, please)

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to read file into `Uint8Array` forever, thanks for your comment paa!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified JS that works for me as illustration only -
You first get the file as array buffer  (e.target.result) then convert it to Uint8 array and pass it to PDF.js as data (docInitParams) instead of a URL

```js
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
 
     var myData = new Uint8Array(e.target.result)
  var docInitParams = { data: myData };
 
  PDFJS.getDocument(docInitParams).then(function(pdf) {.....})   
    
}
```